# Raising X11 urgent flag from webbrowser

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, x11

The global picture is that I want my Firefox X11 window to have its urgent flag set when (say) a new Gmail mail arrives.

I feel confident that I can produce the code to check Gmails arrival by reading some other Firefox extensions' code.  What I can't figure out is how to get the Window ID of the webbrowser, so that I can call, say, an external program to raise the urgent flag (that is, setting the XUrgencyHint).

Any help appreciated; if my methodology (i.e. create an extension) is no good, don't hesitate to say so.

Answer (score 1):

While you did not mention your programming/scripting language you where planning to use to find firefox's window to set, I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062422/588079) to your exact question (both questions are essentially the same: find ff window in x11).

Generally spoken, in firefox each 'container of tabs' is a window and each tab is a window (hence you can load firefox ui inside firefox ui). So you could search for firefox windows with a specific title or src/url.

But.. since you are after a open gmail-tab in firefox anyway.. why not *think inside the box* instead of outside the box.. (I know, feels strange right :) ?)
Why not craft a simple bookmarklet (called something like 'monitor new gmail') and add it to your bookmarks(-bar) (working around FaceFox's -yes I made this diss- insanity of not accepting web-standard javascript in the address-bar anymore..).
This bookmark should do:

- make gmail check for new mail periodically (it'll be AJAX-like
  anyway),
- detect new mail (by comparing the contents of the first row
  in the table that holds the mail-subjects or what ever you can hook)
- and finally set [window.getAttention()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getAttention) (for firefox)
  **OR** (a little more cross-browser:) change document-title OR alternate/change blinking/non-blinking favicon.. 
  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486706/possible-to-flash-a-browser-window-using-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar) topic on SO for some simple and nifty scripts on doing this.