# What happened to window.getAttention() and what can I use instead?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to make an extension that'll get the user's attention when they are outside of the browser. Mozilla previously mentioned Window.getAttention() that would get the user's attention dependent on the operating system, such as flashing th windows in the Windows taskbar. https://web.archive.org/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getAttention
However, by 2018 it listed no browsers as supporting it. Is there an alternative I can use that will still try to get the attention when needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to flash a Browser window using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486706/possible-to-flash-a-browser-window-using-javascript)

Comment: You probably won't find much; most of the attention grabbing features in browsers have been disabled or significantly toned down because of how they were abused by advertisers and other generally shady people who liked to do annoying things with them.

Comment: @Herohtar Yeah, as I was typing this I figured they were disabled because of abuse... that's a shame